# sqlite inserting values into a table from python

Tags: database, sqlite

```
cur.execute("Create table emails(email text, name text, count integer);")
 
cur.execute('''insert into table emails(email, name, count) values(?,?,0)''',(email,name,))
```

this gives me this traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Desktop\python course\my code\database.py", line 20, in 
> cur.execute('''insert into table emails(email, name, count) values(?,?,0)''',(email,name,))
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "table": syntax error

I don't know why it is wrong

Comment: the command is INSERT INTO emails (...) VALUES (...) so get rid of the word table

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2 ,..)
VALUES( value1, value2 ,...);
```

You should replace "table" with the name of the table you want the items to be stored in.

To this:

```
INSERT INTO emails(email, name, count) VALUES(?,?,0)
```